# How can I exclude all letters without making 26 different statements?

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to make an easier statement instead of 26 other "NOT LIKE" statements, anyone have any idea how to do that ? So I can include all letters of the alphabet instead of just the many individual letters. Thank you.

```
SELECT *
FROM name
WHERE flag LIKE 'Y'
AND name.autotrackchild IS NULL
AND substring(name.lot,LENGTH(name.lot),length(name.lot)) NOT LIKE 'A'
AND substring(name.lot,LENGTH(name.lot),length(name.lot)) NOT LIKE 'B'
AND substring(name.lot,LENGTH(name.lot),length(name.lot)) NOT LIKE 'C'
--REMOVES CHILD LOTS (ANYTHING WITH A LETTER ON THE END OF IT'S LENGTH)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use regular expressions:

```
where flag like 'Y' and
      regexp_like(name.lot, '[^A-Z]$')
```

Comment: Well unfortunately our lots have a letter at the beginning of their names. so wouldn't that filter out everything ? For instance a typical lot would be L01234567, then when a lot breaks off another letter is appended, for example L01234567A or L01234567B. Is there a way to filter out just end characters?

Comment: @Dotexe . . . This only looks at the last letter.  That is what the `$` does.

Answer (score 1):

The following is sufficient for the goal:

```
and right(name.lot, 1) not between 'A' and 'Z'
```